# WCF Headache - Auth via HTTP with User Name and Password

Tags: web-services, wcf, passwords, peoplesoft

All,

I am trying to make a .net WCF call that I think should be simple but has proved incredibly difficult.  I could really use some help and in full disclosure I am a WCF newbie.  Here's the scenario:

1. I am trying to call a PeopleSoft CI web service, from C#, that is secured with a user name and password on the PeopleSoft side.
2. The core problem is that the security headers, such as username and password, are not being sent correctly to the PeopleSoft web service.
3. I have done a lot of research and made a lot of attempts over the last several days and made some progress but the bottom line is that I can not get this to work.
4. The items presented below are my original starting blocks and I will not cloud the thread with all of the options I have tried.
5. The original WSDL pointed to a standard HTTP site.  I have tried this with HTTPS as well thinking this would solve the problem.  No luck
6. The web service schema is the following:

   ```
    <HEADER>
       <USERID>myID</USERID>
       <PASSWORD>????</PASSWORD>
       <LANGUAGE_CD>ENG</LANGUAGE_CD>
     </HEADER>
     <that>Ithid</that>
     <Strcurrent_action>target</Strcurrent_action>
     <Strnew_action>action</Strnew_action>
     <StractionConfirm>action</StrpasswordConfirm>
   </MyAction__This__Stuff_SELF>
   ```

   - I generated the C# class and config file from svcutil.  The app.config appears as such:

     ```
     <system.serviceModel>
         <bindings>
             <basicHttpBinding>
                 <binding name="MyStuff_Binding" />
             </basicHttpBinding>
         </bindings>
     ```
   - I make the call with the following code:

     MyStuff_PortTypeClient client = new MyStuff_PortTypeClient("MyStuff_Port");
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "MyLogon";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "MyPassword";
        MyAction__CompIntfc__USER_PROFILETypeShape actionShape = new  MyAction__CompIntfc__USER_PROFILETypeShape();
         UserIDTypeShape targetUser = new UserIDTypeShape();
         try
         {client.MyStuff_MyAction(actionShape);  //Make the call}
   - As I mentioned I have tried this numerous ways including changing the security, message and transport options in basicHttpBinding, trying this with wsHttpBinding,custom headers etc...and no joy.
   - I would really appreciate any assistance and successful examples of how to call a PeopleSoft web service secured with a user name and password over http or https.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I too had a lot of trouble but got it to work... sort of. I had to manually put the header in the config file like so...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="PeopleSoft_Binding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint name="MyEndpoint"
                bindingConfiguration="PeopleSoft_Binding"                    
                contract="ProxyClass.ProxyClass_PortType"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                address="https://MyPeoplesoftInstance/PeopleSoftServiceListeningConnector">
        <headers>
          <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" 
                         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
                         xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
              <wsse:Username>TheUser</wsse:Username>
              <wsse:Password>ThePassword</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
          </wsse:Security>
        </headers>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Then, call it the normal way ...

```
using (var client = new MyProxy.MyProxy_PortTypeClient("MyEndpoint"))
        {
            client.MyMethod();
        }
```

Although this is working, it is not ideal since the credentials are stored in the config file. Ideally, I would like to be able to pass the credentials programmatically and I've tried a bunch of stuff involving the XmlSerializer, WCF configuration etc. but nothing has worked so far. Hopefully, this answer will get someone to the next step.